# blazor return RenderFragment '__builder' does not exist in the current context

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm trying to return a `RenderFragment` from a component private method,
but I'm getting the compilation error:

```
'__builder' does not exist in the current context
```

here's the minimum code that shows the problem:

```
<div>
    @RenderButton(1)
</div>

@code {
    private RenderFragment RenderButton(int number)
    {        
        return builder =>
        {
            <button type="button">@number</button>
        };
    }
}
```

it appears to me that this might not be possible/allowed, if not, is there any way to avoid having to write the same render code?, let's say that I need to use this `RenderButton` method in multiple loops, and if else blocks

edit: the only solution I can think of now is to create a component for each of these `RenderFragment` methods

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code seems to be for an earlier version of Blazor.

Blazor now has a more elegant notation, using [templated delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#templated-razor-delegates):

```cs
private RenderFragment RenderButton(int number) 
{
     return @<button type="button">@number</button>;
}
```

The explanation for your error is that `__builder` is a fixed name, used by the transpiler. You could also fix your code like this:

```cs
// not recommended
private RenderFragment RenderButton(int number)
{        
    return __builder =>
    {
        <button type="button">@number</button>
    };
}
```

The razor compiler is able to do a smart switch on the `@` and `;` and inserts the `__builder => ...` part behind the curtains.