# Change Component Index at runtime

Tags: razor, blazor

How do i change index of Blazor's Component Index at runtime.
Here is code of razor

```html
@page "/datagrid"
 @namespace PS
 
 
 <div class="input-group">  
     <DxDateEdit  @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>

     <DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>
 </div>


      
      
  

 @code
{
    DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; } = new DateTime(2022, 1, 1);
    public bool IsDisplayTextBoxFirst { get; set; } = false;

 }
```

**current Output**
[image]

when user set value **IsDisplayTextBoxFirst** to true then Textbox should rendered at first like attached image
[image]
How do i change component index at runtime according to value of **IsDisplayTextBoxFirst** property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `if`/`else` expression inside your `.input-group`, as follows:

```
<div class="input-group">
    @if (IsDisplayTextBoxFirst)
    {
        <DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>
        <DxDateEdit @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <DxDateEdit @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>        
        <DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>
    }
</div>
```

Alternatively, define [reusable `RenderFragment`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-3.1#define-reusable-renderfragments-in-code-2) in your code:

```
<div class="input-group">
    @if (IsDisplayTextBoxFirst)
    {
        @TextBox
        @DateEdit
    }
    else
    {
        @DateEdit
        @TextBox
    }
</div>

@code
{
    // Parameters and other logic

    private RenderFragment TextBox => __builder =>
    {
        <DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>
    };

    private RenderFragment DateEdit => __builder =>
    {
        <DxDateEdit @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>
    };
}
```

As suggested by @henk-holtermann, you could optionally implement the reusable `RenderFragments` [using `templated delegates`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096198/blazor-return-renderfragment-builder-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context/70096867#70096867) ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#templated-razor-delegates)) and not need to reference the `__builder` at all:

```
@code
{
    // Parameters and other logic

    private RenderFragment TextBox => @<DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>;

    private RenderFragment DateEdit => @<DxDateEdit @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to implement second approach , but Exception throw __builder does not exist in the current context

Comment: My bad, it's corrected now! (I had used `_builder`, but it should be `__builder` (two underscores))

Comment: [No need for `__builder` at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70096867/60761): `RenderFragment DateEdit =>
@<DxDateEdit @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional rendering and have you code like this

```
<div class="input-group">  
     <DxDateEdit  @bind-Date="@DateTimeValue"/>
     @if(IsDisplayTextBoxFirst){
       <DxTextBox Text="This is textbox"/>
     }
 </div>
```